# Is "anche" used in negative sentences?

Tags: adverbs

Can "anche" be used instead of "neanche" in negative sentences? Example:

> Non ho vinto anch'io.

Comment: Personally I would say: _Anch'io non ho vinto_ or _Neanche io ho vinto_.

Comment: If you want to say (as I guess) that you haven't won you should use "non ho vinto NEANCH'IO" (unless you change the words order like @abarisone did). Saying "Non ho vinto anche io" sounds incomplete to me and seems to suggest "non ho vinto anche io [ma SOLO io]".

Comment: @OldManofAran Sorry, but I haven't understood what you meant in the last sentence. non ho vinto anche io [ma SOLO io] = I have not won either [but ONLY me] ?

Comment: If I understand correctly @OldManofAran, he means (and I agree with him) that _non ho vinto anch'io_ sounds like “It's not the case that ‘I won too’, since I was the only one to win”.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have some information about the use of *anche* in negative sentences you could have a look to the concept of *[negazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/negazione_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)* on Treccani's Enciclopedia dell'Italiano.

In particular:

> (b) Le congiunzioni *neanche* (< *né* + *anche*; ➔ univerbazione), *nemmeno*
>   (< né + meno) e *neppure* (< né + pure), che aggiungono un elemento
>   negativo ad altri già espressi nel contesto precedente, come in non mi
>   piace il tennis e neanche (o nemmeno o neppure) il calcio. Neanche e
>   nemmeno possono anche avere valore rafforzativo, indicando
>   l’esclusione di ogni possibilità: per es., non oso neanche (o nemmeno
>   o neppure) chiederglielo.

About the syntax, you can read:

> Le frasi negative si distinguono da quelle positive perché alle prime
>   si possono aggiungere altri elementi tramite la congiunzione *neanche*
>   (3 a.); le frasi positive ammettono invece l’aggiunta di altri
>   elementi solo tramite anche (3 b.):
>
> (3)    a. io non ti sento, neanche lui
>
> (3)    b. io ti sento, anche lui
>
> I prefissi negativi elencati in (e) nel § 2 non esprimono il valore
>   negativo della polarità; la presenza di parole così formate non rende
>   la frase negativa:
>
> (4) Giovanni è infelice, anche [*neanche] Maria lo è.

Regarding your example, personally I would say:

> Anch'io non ho vinto

or

> Neanche io ho vinto.

Comment: I am not sure I understood it right. Is "Giovanni è infelice, anche Maria lo è" = "Giovanni è infelice, neanche Maria lo è" = "Giovanni is unhappy, Maria is too" ?

Comment: Also, I'd like to see an explicit answer to my question. Are "Non ho vinto anch'io" and "Non ho vinto neanch'io" both correct and meaningful? Do they mean exactly the same? Do they mean exactly the same what your suggested sentences with anch/neanch'io at the beginning of the sentence mean? Sorry if the Treccani quotes have already answered those questions, but Treccani is difficult to understand sometimes.